# How to locate several buttons(or 'a' tag) at the center in html?

Tags: html, css

I want to locate two `a` tags at the center of window.

Here is what I tried:

```
<div class="row">
    <table class="table table-user-information center" style="width:50%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td> I D </td>
            <td> abcdefg </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> 이 름 </td>
            <td> 홍길동 </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> 생 일 </td>
            <td> 1988.01.24 </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> 성 별 </td>
            <td> 남 </td>
          <tr>
            <td> Email </td>
            <td> abcdefg@gmail.com </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="button-holder" style="text-align:center;display:block; width:20%;">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> 비밀번호 변경 </a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> 회원탈퇴 </a>
    </div>
</div> <!-- row -->
```

But it doesn't work.. It looks like this :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I succeeded only one `a` tag, but locating two tags is kinda different.
Need your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Bootstrap.

Add `text-center` along with your "button-holder" class

```
<div class="button-holder text-center">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> 비밀번호 변경 </a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> 회원탈퇴 </a>
</div>
```

And you dont even need to add inline css to make it center horizontally:
So you can remove `style="text-align:center;display:block; width:100%;"`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following instead

```
.button-holder {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```